# Need advice on removing xml row

Tags: c#, xpath

I'm using a CMS and found a function to generate a rss feed from content within folders. However I would like one of the rows removing from the list. I've done my research and I 'think' I should be using XmlDocument class to help me remove the row I don't want. I've used Firebug and FirePath to get the XPath - but I cant seem to figure out how to apply it appropriately. I am also uncertain of whether I should be using .Load or .LoadXml - I've used the latter seing as though the feed displays fine. However I have had to convert ToString() to get rid of that overloaded match error....

The row I want removing is called "Archived Planes"
The XPath I get for FirePath is ".//*[@id='feedContent']/xhtml:div[11]/xhtml:h3/xhtml:a"

I am also assuming that .RemoveChild(node); will remove it out of rssData before I Response.Write. Thanks

```
Object rssData = new object();
Cms.UI.CommonUI.ApplicationAPI AppAPI = new Cms.UI.CommonUI.ApplicationAPI();
rssData = AppAPI.ecmRssSummary(50, true, "DateCreated", 0, "");
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";

XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

xmlDocument.LoadXml(rssData.ToString());

XmlNode node = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode(@"xhtml:div/xhtml:h3/xhtml[a = 'Archived Planes']");

    if (node != null)
    {
        node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
    }

Response.Write(rssData);
```

### Edited to include output below

```
This is the what the response.write from rssData is pumping out:
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<rss xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Plane feed</title>
<link>http://www.domain.rss1.aspx</link>
<description></description>
<item>
<title>New Planes</title>
<link>http://www.domainx1.aspx</link>
<description>
This is the description
</description>
<author>Andrew</author>
<pubDate>Thu, 16 Aug 2012 15:55:53 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
<item>
<title>Archived Planes</title>
<link>http://www.domain23.aspx</link>
<description>
Description of Archived Planes
</description>
<author>Jan</author>
<pubDate>Wed, 15 Aug 2012 10:34:23 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your xpath is incorrect, it looks like some funky dom element that you are referencing and not the xml element... e.g. for the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
 <userinfo>
     <username>pqr2</username>
     <pass>abc</pass>
     <addr>abc</addr>
 </userinfo>

 <userinfo>
     <username>pqr1</username>
     <pass>pqr2</pass>
     <addr>pqr3</addr>
 </userinfo>
</NewDataSet>
```

This code will remove the userinfo node with an username element of pqr1

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(@"file.xml");
XmlNode node = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode(@"NewDataSet/userinfo[username = 'pqr1']");

if (node != null) {
  node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
  xmlDocument.Save(@"file.xml");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, think I have figured out the XPath, this seems to work xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("rss/channel/item[title = 'Archived Planes']"); - what is the purpose of the @ symbol? Ive remove this and  it seems to work. The final piece of the puzzle is how do I save to the rssData object, as the .Save I think only saves to a physical file?

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would post the answer, although I'll mark Pauls as the answer, as his code/advice was the basis of this and my further research. Still don't know what the '@' in SelectSingleNode is and whether I should really have it - will do more research.

```
    Object rssData = new object();
    Cms.UI.CommonUI.ApplicationAPI AppAPI = new Cms.UI.CommonUI.ApplicationAPI();
    rssData = AppAPI.ecmRssSummary(50, true, "DateCreated", 0, "");
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

    xmlDocument.LoadXml(rssData.ToString());

    XmlNode node = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("rss/channel/item[title = 'Archived Planes']");

    if (node != null)
        try
        {
            node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
            xmlDocument.Save(Response.Output);
        }
        catch { }

    else { Response.Write(rssData); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The @ symbol is simply to denote a verbatim string literal (allows you to have funky characters in the string compared to the normal string declaration) e.g.

```
string e = "Joe said \"Hello\" to me";      // Joe said "Hello" to me
string f = @"Joe said ""Hello"" to me";   // Joe said "Hello" to me
```

See [this msdn link for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense.Will add the @ sign in again